# Handle key shortcuts across all windows forms application but not in other processes

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

I need to launch a new search form from all the open windows of my application if the user presses `Control + F`.

Currently I am using windows user32.dll methods to register a hotkey that I want to show across my application like this:

```
// Registers a hot key with Windows.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
// Unregisters the hot key with Windows.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

The issue with this method is that the shortcut is launched even when a different application like a web browser is selected.

I have tried using `MainForm_KeyDown` with `KeyPreview` set to true but it only works for the main form. I also tried overriding `ProcessCmdKey` but again, it only works for the main form.

I was thinking that maybe the UI Automation library offers support to watch for input. Otherwise would it be possible to add a filter to the windows hotkey registration so that it only works for the process id of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have these requirements:

- Control-F makes a new form
- Regardless of which Form (or control) has the focus currently, the hotkey should still work.
- The hotkey is local to the application.

Implementing `IMessageFilter` should be effective in achieving these objectives:

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                switch((Keys)m.WParam | ModifierKeys)
                {
                    case Keys.Control | Keys.F:
                        onNewForm();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    int _count = 0;
    private void onNewForm()
    {
        char c = (char)(_count + 'A');
        int dim = ++_count * SystemInformation.CaptionHeight;
        new TextBoxForm
        {
            Name = $"textBoxForm{c}",
            Text = $"TextBoxForm {c}",
            Size = this.Size,
            StartPosition= FormStartPosition.Manual,
            Location = new Point(Left + dim, Top + dim),
        }.Show(this);
    }
}
```